# django-modeltranslation show all languages forms

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I want to show 3 forms (with different language) simultaneously
Languages:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('fr', 'French'),
    ('ja', 'Japanese'),
)
```

model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class TestOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name', 'desc',)

translator.register(Test, TestOptions)
```

form:

```
class TestForm(TranslationModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['name', 'desc']
```

and then want to show 3 form (en/fr/ja) that not depend on user selected language

> django-modeltranslation==0.10.1
>
> Django==1.8.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `modeltranslation.admin.TranslationAdmin`?
Cf. doc http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html